# How to upload files in my custom Integromat app?

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am implementing an API that supports image upload. How to pass an image into an Integromat module and send it to the server?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how to upload a file in the module. You can check how we upload files in our example Apps:

**application/octet-stream**: https://www.integromat.com/app/dropbox/5/module/uploadFile

**multipart/form-data**: https://www.integromat.com/app/pipedrive/2/module/UploadFile

More info about how to implement multipart/form-data here: https://docs.integromat.com/apps/structure-blocks/api/multipart-form-data

Answer (score 0):

I think the question entails using HTTP module.

You need to host the file somewhere in Dropbox or Google drive... AWS or anywhere on the web.

Use HTTP module to download the file (put file URL in the settings of the blue hTTP module), then link Data to the next module..

We have done this with Facebook Messenger application when user shared pictures or files